# Class error: class not declared. may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net

I have been setting up an application that will read variables from input from a previous form.

```
Public Sub frmGame_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim index As Integer
Dim index1 As Integer

    For index1 = 1 To 6
        For index = 1 To 11

            If index1 = 1 Then
                If index = 1 AndAlso index = frmPicks.pickOne Then
                    ptrTopOne.Image = ptrWarriorImage.Image
                    Dim topOne As New Warrior
```

after running an if-then comparison(because i have several different classes to be made, based on the variables data), i create a new class based on the variable in this frmGame_Enter sub. The classes are completely set up, and the class being created is calling from it, no problems.

However, in my Hoverover sub, it is unable to find the new declaration, stating: 
"Class" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

```
Private Sub ptrTopOne_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ptrTopOne.MouseHover
    If p1Turn = True Then
        If hoverOff = False Then
            HoverOver = 1
            If topOne.getMoveProperties() = 0 Then
                btnMoveBox.Hide()
```

It is unable to read the new declaration in the frmGame_Load sub?

my question then would be:
How am i able to declare my new classes in my code so that it declares at form load, and can still use comparisons?

I will try to clarify better if this isnt clear enough, very sorry. There are several lines of code, i just took a bit to reference. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why did you tag this c++?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue is described correctly.  It appears that you're concerned with the variable topOne.  Which looks like a variable scope issue.  topOne only exists within the condition "If index = 1 AndAlso index = frmPicks.pickOne".  As soon as that condition is closed (end if) that variable disappears.

If you want to use that in both functions, it needs to be declared at the form level.